# Pie chart text is not showing correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart

I have written the below code but pie chart is showing [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxVht.png)

```
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Apr", "Jun"]
        let unitsSold = [68, 10, 12, 10]
    setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Int]) {
        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let width = screenBounds.width
        let height = screenBounds.height
        let frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: width, height: height/1.5)
        let chart = PieChartView(frame: frame)
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(values[i]), y: Double(i))
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        var colors: [UIColor] = []
        for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
            colors.append(color)

        }
        pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
        let data = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
        piecharView.data = data
        piecharView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        piecharView.noDataText = "No Data Available"
        piecharView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
         let d = Description()
        d.text = ""
        piecharView.chartDescription = d
        piecharView.centerText = "HEALTH SCORE"
        piecharView.holeRadiusPercent = 0.5
        piecharView.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.clear
        piecharView.usePercentValuesEnabled = true
        piecharView.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = true

        pieChartDataSet.colors = colors

    }
```

But I want like this 
[pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkcGx.png)
 I have enabled the percentage but still not showing the pie chart what I want.

[Now it is showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLv3x.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line          `let data = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)`

put this code

```
    let pFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    pFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    pFormatter.multiplier = 1
    pFormatter.percentSymbol = " %"
    data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: pFormatter))

    data.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11)!)
    data.setValueTextColor(.white)
```

And after that

```
    piecharView.data = data
```

and

```
    piecharView.setNeedDisplay()
```

**EDIT**

**Step 1**: Goto Storybaord and set proper constraint to pieChartView 
**Step 2**: In storyboard select PieCharView and set it class `PieChartView` from right panel. 
**Step 3**: remove old IBOutlet and attach new IBoutlet should looks like

```
@IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: PieChartView!
```

Add this method in you class

```
func setCharts(dataPoints:[String], values : [Double]) {
    var dataEntries = [PieChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry =  PieChartDataEntry(value: values[i], label: dataPoints[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Unit Sold")
    pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 3
    pieChartDataSet.selectionShift = 5

    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }

    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors

    let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)

    let pFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    pFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    pFormatter.multiplier = 1
    pFormatter.percentSymbol = " %"
    pieChartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: pFormatter))

    pieChartData.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11)!)
    pieChartData.setValueTextColor(.white)


    self.pieChartView.data = pieChartData
    self.pieChartView.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.pieChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0,easingOption: .easeOutElastic)
}
```

And From `viewDidLoad` paste following

```
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]

    setCharts(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
```

**Output :**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

```
    var attrString: NSMutableAttributedString?

    let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HEALTH SCORE HEALTH SCORE HEALTH SCORE HEALTH SCORE")
    attrString?.setAttributes([
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSUIColor.black,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0),
        NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ], range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString!.length))

    pieChartView.centerAttributedText =  attrString
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: I have applied your code but still text is not showing properly even centre text Is same as it was before @Prashany Tukadiya

Comment: Try to remove extra properties like  `holeRadiusPercent` etc and increase height of pie chart

Comment: See I have attached screenshot again what I get after your code applied

Comment: Yes I have removed hole radius and increased the height let frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: width, height: height/0.5) but still centre text is not showing correctly , only four characters are showng

Comment: @user9483522 You are not using `chart` property you have defined in your method ? `let chart = PieChartView(frame: frame)` check  frame of your `piecharView`

Comment: I have used it piecharView.addSubview(chart)

Comment: Everything is fine sir but only the problem is centre text is not showing properly, otherwise all values showing correctly, can you please help me to show the text at the centre

Comment: @user9483522 I am not aware will back with solution soon. if possible :)

Comment: @user9483522 Check edit2  fixed with attributed text

Comment: yes sir now it is working fine thank you ver much, I don't have sufficient point otherwise I will upvote your answer

Comment: @user9483522 no problem :)